# React returning Error decoder message message

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create very simple multistep form using react. My main component which is handling state for steps looks like this:

```
...

renderStepItem = () => {
switch(this.state.step) {
  case 1:
    return  <ImportStep nextStep={this.nextStep} />
  case 2:
    return  <ImportStep previousStep={this.previousStep} nextStep={this.nextStep} />
  case 3:
    return  <ImportStep previousStep={this.previousStep} />
}
}

...
```

This is switch which should return Component that should be rendered based on step state

Then render:

```
render() {
  return(
    {this.renderStepItem()}
  )
}
```

The problem is that i am getting following error message:

**Error**

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {nextStep}).
```

I was trying to go through some tuts etc to solve it. But i am guessing that i am passing something that i am unable to do.

Can anybody give me some hint please?

## UPDATE:

```
render() {

    const importSteps = AppConfig.importSteps;

    return (
      <Block extend={{
        width: '80%',
        margin: '25px auto'
      }}>
        <TabNav extend={{
          border: '1px solid black',
        }}
          textAlign='center'>
          {Object.keys(importSteps).map(function(key) {
            return <TabNavItem >{importSteps[key].name} {importSteps[key].stepNo}</TabNavItem>;
          }
          )}
        </TabNav>
        <div>{ this.renderStepItem() }</div>
      </Block>
    )
  }
}
```

## UPDATE2: ImportItem component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Block } from 'vcc-ui';

class ImportStep extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Block>
        <h3>{this.props}</h3>
      </Block>
    )
  }
}

export default ImportStep;
```

Comment: Try `return (<ImportStep nextStep={this.nextStep} />)` (notice the added parenthesis, apply to each return statement)

Comment: can you add a sample of `ImportStep` ?

Comment: Can you check to make sure that you transcribed the render method correctly for us? As written I would expect it to be a syntax error, because those curly brackets don't make sense in this context.

Comment: i have some constants before render. so i need those curlys. and importstep basically is very similiar to this. imagine <div>hello</div> is returned

Comment: @MartinFric Unfortunately, we're not able to debug your code by imagining it. With the information provided, all i can tell you is that either your main render method or your ImportStep's render method is returning an object as a child. And evidently its an object with a `nextStep` property on it. If you can provide the missing code (ie, both render methods), perhaps we can help narrow it down.

Comment: i updated story guys. First is whole render function, second is ImportItem component

Comment: @MartinFric Thanks for the update. The issue is in ImportStep when you do `<h3>{this.props}</h3>`. this.props is an object, and you're trying to render that object as a child of the h3, which is not allowed. What is it you're intending to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Use `this.props.property` in the render function. You can not use an `object` there in the `ImportStep` component.

Also, wrapping inside a `<div>` would be necessary when you have only one statement inside the return.

Wrap your `this.renderStepItem()` inside a `<div></div>`, and that should do.

Here is what your return statement should look like,

```
return (
  <div>{ this.renderStepItem() }</div>
)
```

See this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/q35699jj49

Comment: In your ImportStep component, you are adding `this.props` in render method which is not correct, it's an `object`. Try with `this.props.nextStep` or other props which you are passing.

Comment: Also, my guess is that `<div>` is required if there is only one line inside render function's return, but now that you have given the complete render method, it wouldn't be necessary here.